# Sharepoint 2013 accessing external list in workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, external-list

I have created an external list using WCF connections. I have in that list all the information that I need.
Now I need to access that data from another list workflow(sharepoint 2013 platform workflow). I know that can be done using sp 2010 workflows platform because in dropdown source inside the workflow, my external list is listed. However in sp 2013 I can't find my external list inside a workflow.
can you help me?
thank you